# What does Clojure's zip-map do?

Tags: clojure, zipmap

I am new at Clojure and I needed help with this function. If you could please tell me what this function does and how it works I would be really thankfull.

```
(defn zip-map
  [k v]
    (into{} (map vec (partition 2 (interleave k v)))))
```

Comment: Did you even try to understand what the individual functions do?

Comment: Yes I tried to understand each part of the function. My problem is that I am having a hard time to understand the entire function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Example of usage:

```
(zip-map [:a :b :c] [1 2 3]) ;=> {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3}
```

And from the inside out:

```
(interleave [:a :b :c] [1 2 3]) ;=> (:a 1 :b 2 :c 3)
(partition 2 '(:a 1 :b 2 :c 3)) ;=> ((:a 1) (:b 2) (:c 3))
(map vec '((:a 1) (:b 2) (:c 3))) ;=> ([:a 1] [:b 2] [:c 3])
(into {} '([:a 1] [:b 2] [:c 3])) ;=> {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3}
```

Comment: @AlvaritoDaSilva, do not forget that you can upvote answers that seem to be helpful and select best answer by clicking on `V` mark beside the answer.

Comment: @Mark Whenever I see the accept checkmark referred to as a "V" I get rather confused: it really does not look anything like a V, and if I didn't already know what you're talking about I would not easily be able to find it. It's not that hard to use a real Unicode ✓ symbol to point out the accept button.

Answer (score 2):

The function is more complicated hence harder to understand than it need be. It could be written thus:

```
(defn zip-map [ks vs]
  (into {} (map vector ks vs)))
```

when

```
(zip-map [:a :b :c] [1 2 3])
;{:a 1, :b 2, :c 3}
```

as before.

The function imitates the standard `zipmap`, which you can find explained, complete with source code, in the [official docs](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/zipmap) or [ClojureDocs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/zipmap), which also gives examples. Both these sites help you to pick your way through the Clojure vocabulary.

As is often the case, the standard function is faster though more complex than the simple one-liner above.